# Default units in expl3

Tags: expl3, dimensions, unit-of-measure, dimension-expressions

So I have produced code, which I think is kind of a hack, but it seems to work so far in my testing.
I have setup a new `expl3` function that sets a dimen variable.
If the input for the dimen expression does not contain a unit known to TeX, then the unit defaults to `pt`.

I have seen non-`expl3` packages have interfaces where users can set a dimen variable and have the unit default to `pt`.
For example, the `fontsize` package has a package option `fontsize=<fontsize>` where, if the unit for `<fontsize>` is not given, it is automatically set to `pt`.

My question is: Is there a better and more formal way to set a default unit (`pt`, `bp` `pc`, etc.) to a unitless expression when writing classes or packages in `expl3` ?

I provide my minimal working example below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \regex_match:Nn { NV } { TF }
\tl_new:N \l__module_tmpa_tl
\dim_new:N \l__module_tmpa_dim
% Checks if the input contains any unit known to TeX.
% This regex is based off the regex given in section 8.1.1 of interface3.pdf.
\regex_const:Nn \c_module_contains_any_unit_regex
{ (?i)pt|in|[cem]m|ex|[bs]p|[dn]d|[pcn]c }
\cs_new:Nn \__module_dim_set_with_default_unit:Nn
{
    \tl_set:Nx \l__module_tmpa_tl { #2 }
    \regex_match:NVTF
    \c_module_contains_any_unit_regex \l__module_tmpa_tl
    {  \dim_set:Nn #1 { \l__module_tmpa_tl }  }
    {   \dim_set:Nn #1 {  \fp_eval:n { \l__module_tmpa_tl } pt  }   }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn % only for testing purposes
\__module_dim_set_with_default_unit:Nn \l__module_tmpa_dim { 10 } % without unit
\dim_use:N \l__module_tmpa_dim % the unit defaults to pt
\newline
\__module_dim_set_with_default_unit:Nn \l__module_tmpa_dim { 10bp } % with unit
\dim_use:N \l__module_tmpa_dim
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a regex here is slow and will say a value such as `\textwidth` requires a unit.

LaTeX already provides `\@defaultunitsset` using the method wipet showed

```
\@defaultunitsset dimen value default
```

where `default` can be a unit or length such as `\unitlength` used in picture mode.

You could use that directly or more naturally in expl3 give it an L3 name which would allow variants to be generated, so

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l__module_tmpa_dim

\cs_new_eq:Nc \__module_dim_set_with_default_unit:Nnn {@defaultunitsset}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__module_dim_set_with_default_unit:Nn #1#2
  {
    \__module_dim_set_with_default_unit:Nnn #1 { #2 }{ pt }
  }

\__module_dim_set_with_default_unit:Nn \l__module_tmpa_dim { 10 } 

\dim_show:N \l__module_tmpa_dim

\__module_dim_set_with_default_unit:Nn \l__module_tmpa_dim { 10 bp} 

\dim_show:N \l__module_tmpa_dim

\stop
```

producing

```
> \l__module_tmpa_dim=10.0pt.
<recently read> }

l.13 \dim_show:N \l__module_tmpa_dim

?
> \l__module_tmpa_dim=10.03749pt.
<recently read> }

l.17 \dim_show:N \l__module_tmpa_dim

?
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Follow-up question. Let's say that I want to make a new command called `\__module_dim_gset_with_default_unit:Nn` that is global instead of local. Would I just prefix `\global` to `\@defaultunitsset` in this case?

Comment: @User23456234 no you'd need the global before the assignment not before the `\afterassignment` so `\def\@gdefaultunitsset#1#2#3{%
  \@defaultunits\global#1\dimexpr#2#3\relax\relax\@nnil}`

Comment: @egreg https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64271731#64271731

Comment: @User23456234 or you could use `\cs_new_protected:Npn \__module_dim_gset_with_default_unit:Nn #1#2 { \group_begin: \__module_dim_set_with_default_unit:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {#2} \dim_gset_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_dim \group_end: }` (would save you from knowing the internal definition of `\@defaultunits`).

Comment: @Skillmon sure but that would spoil the "latex already provides this" narrative

Comment: May I kindly suggest that expl3 should have something like `\@defaultunitsset` ? I think it would be useful for creating user level interfaces and commands.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, wouldn't `\cs_new_protected:Npn \__module_dim_(g)set_with_default_unit:Nnn #1#2#3 { \@defaultunits \dim_set:Nn #1 { #2 #3 } \@nnil }` and `\cs_new_protected:Npn \__module_skip_(g)set_with_default_unit:Nnn #1#2#3 { \@defaultunits \skip_set:Nn #1 { #2 #3 } \@nnil }` work just as well? Perhaps the syntax fits in better with expl3 style.

Comment: @User23456234 quite possibly. The above comment was just a quick response not a considered design.

Answer (score 10):

I don't understand your code because the `expl3` is too complicated for me, but you can compare, how to solve your task using TeX primitive `\afterassignment`. It seems to be more simple and more straightforward.

```
\def\setdimen#1#2{%
   \afterassignment\setdimenA
   #1=#2pt\relax
}
\def\setdimenA#1\relax{}

%%  test:
\newdimen\tmpdim

\setdimen\tmpdim {20}  \the\tmpdim   % prints: 20.0pt

\setdimen\tmpdim {4em} \the\tmpdim   % prints: 40.0pt
```